# Using multiples urls pointing to the same view, can't catch the variable from the url in the view

Tags: python, django, url, formview

I'm using multiples urls pointing to the same View,'cause sometimes I send 2 values to the url and other just one, the problem is in the view when I try to catch the values I does't matter the name on the variable in the url, I use seguros and fac in the url as variables, but when a catch the values in the view it always catch it in the same variable fact,I need to catch them in diferente variables, 'cause in the template where I send them I need to do an if, but I can't. Can someone tell me why this is happening and what can I do so the value of seguro catch it in the variable seguro and the value of fac I catch it in fac. Here is my code.

Template.html

```
{% if facturas %}
    <a style="text-align: center" href="{% url 'seguimientoadministrativourls:crearseguimientoadministrativo' id=post.id_paciente.pk fac=facturas %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span> </a>
{% elif seguros %}
    <a style="text-align: center" href="{% url 'seguimientoadministrativourls:crearseguimientoadministrativo' id=post.id_paciente.pk seguros=seguros %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
</a>
{% else %}
    <a style="text-align: center" href="{% url 'seguimientoadministrativourls:crearseguimientoadministrativo' id=post.id_paciente.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
</a>
{%endif%}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^crearseguimientoadministrativo/(?P<id>\d+)$',
    permission_required(
        'seguimientoadministrativo.add_seguimientoadministrativobitacora',
        login_url='/sin_acceso')(CrearSeguimientoAdministrativo.as_view()),
    name='crearseguimientoadministrativo'),

url(r'^crearseguimientoadministrativo/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<fac>\S+)$',
    permission_required(
        'seguimientoadministrativo.add_seguimientoadministrativobitacora',
        login_url='/sin_acceso')(CrearSeguimientoAdministrativo.as_view()),
    name='crearseguimientoadministrativo'),

url(r'^crearseguimientoadministrativo/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<seguros>\S+)$',
    permission_required(
        'seguimientoadministrativo.add_seguimientoadministrativobitacora',
        login_url='/sin_acceso')(CrearSeguimientoAdministrativo.as_view()),
    name='crearseguimientoadministrativo'),
```

views.py

```
class CrearSeguimientoAdministrativo(ListView):
    template_name = 'crearseguimientoAdmin.html'
    model = SeguimientoAdministrativoBitacora
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        query = DatosPaciente.objects.filter(pk=id)
        return query

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(
           CrearSeguimientoAdministrativo, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['seguimiento'] = SeguimientoAdministrativoBitacora.objects.filter(
        id_paciente=paciente)
      context['factura'] = self.kwargs.get('fac')
      context['seguro'] = self.kwargs.get('seguros')
      return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the URL resolver supposed to distinguish between your URLs? They are both of the form "crearseguimientoadministrativo/numbers/string"; there is no way to tell which string represents a "fac" and which is a "seguros". You need to add some other way of distinguishing; perhaps with `.../<id>/fac/<fac>/` and `.../<id>/seguros/<seguros>/`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer did the job ;)